# Django: Оптимизация ORM-запроса

Tags: django, django-orm

Нужна помощь в оптимизации запроса

```
FederalDistrict.objects.values('id','name').order_by('id').annotate(services_count=Count(Case(
When(Q(subjects__organisations__services__draft=False) & Q(subjects__organisations__services__archive=False), then=F('subjects__organisations__services')))))
```

На чистом SQL он выглядит так:

```
'SELECT 
    "federal_district"."id", 
    "federal_district"."name", 
    COUNT(
        CASE WHEN ("service"."draft" = False AND "service"."archive" = False) 
        THEN "service"."id" ELSE NULL END) AS "services_count" 
FROM 
    "federal_district" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "federation_subject" ON ("federal_district"."id" = "federation_subject"."federal_district_id") 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "organisation" ON ("federation_subject"."id" = "organisation"."federation_subject_id") 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "service" ON ("organisation"."id" = "service"."organisation_id") 

GROUP BY "federal_district"."id" 
ORDER BY "federal_district"."id" ASC'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FederalDistrict.objects
 .select_related("subjects", "subjects__organisations", "subjects__services")
 .only("id", "name", "subjects__organisations__services__draft", "subjects__organisations__services__archive")
 .annotate(
     services_count=Count(
         Case(
             When(
                 Q(subjects__organisations__services__draft=False) & 
                 Q(subjects__organisations__services__archive=False, 
                 then=F('subjects__organisations__services')
             )
         )
     )
 )
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).